# Ruby Mailer: Wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, mailer, postmark

I'm working on building out my mailer, but I keep running into:

> wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Call my crazy, but I feel like I defined everything correctly:

Controller (truncated for brevity):

```
def create
@cms484 = Cms484.new(cms484_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @cms484.save
    SendLink.message(@cms484).deliver_later
    format.html { redirect_to cms484s_path, notice: 'Cms484 was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cms484 }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @cms484.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

SendLink.rb:

```
    class SendLink < ApplicationMailer
    def message(cms484)
    @cms484 = cms484
    mail(
      :subject => 'Hello from Postmark',
      :to  => @cms484.recipient ,
      :from => 'info@mysite.com',
      :html_body => '<strong>Hello</strong> user!.',
  end
end
```

Can anybody else see the needle in the haystack or am I missing something else entirely?

I'm using Postmark for delivery if that matters, and have those parameters defined in my application.rb file as per the documentation.  Think this is a simpler matter though.

**Edit**
The complete error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 76ms

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/mailers/send_link.rb:2:in `message'
  app/mailers/send_link.rb:4:in `message'
  app/controllers/cms484s_controller.rb:38:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/cms484s_controller.rb:36:in `create'
```

Comment: You put comma instead of closing parenthesis for `mail` function in `SendLink.rb`

Comment: Picked that up after posting, not sure what I did there but didn't solve the problem.  Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: I had the same issue. Believe it or not, a server restart and the mailer preview started working, maybe a restart is required after using the mail generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I decided to re-write it and behold - it works.  Why or what's different than the previous version(other than the method email vs mail, surely that can't be it?), I have no idea.  If you can see what it is, **Please** point it out to me!

Send_link.rb:

```
class SendLink < ApplicationMailer



def email(cms484)
    @cms484 = cms484
     mail(
  :subject => 'Hello from Postmark',
  :to  => @cms484.recipient ,
  :from => 'info@mysite.com',
)
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
def create
@cms484 = Cms484.new(cms484_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @cms484.save
    SendLink.email(@cms484).deliver_later

    format.html { redirect_to cms484s_path, notice: 'Cms484 was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cms484 }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @cms484.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue where I named my ActionMailer method "message" it turns out it was a reserved word in Rails and threw an error.

I would assume that "mail" was a reserved word where "email" was not.

Answer (score 0):

`mail ...` line in `SendLink.rb` looks wrong , change it to,

```
 mail(
  :subject => 'Hello from Postmark',
  :to  => @cms484.recipient ,
  :from => 'info@mysite.com',
  :html_body => '<strong>Hello</strong> user!.')
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference in what I posted and your suggestion?  Copied and pasted suggestion just to be sure and still seeing same 0 for 1 error.

Comment: Its a syntax problem, checkout `, and ) ` . But i think this isn't solved your  problem as mentioned in question's comments. So keep going.