# ActionMailer 4.2.6 giving `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` on `deliver_later(wait: 1.hour)`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq

I'm trying to send a simple email that needs to be delayed for on hour. Emails overall work well and I can call `deliver_now` and `deliver_later` with no problem. However, if I call the same email `deliver_later(wait: 1.hour)` (as documented here: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later) I get the following error:

> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0))

On the same line as `deliver_later(wait: 1.hour)`. The stack trace doesn't show any other lines in my code.

Here's my mailer:

```
def project_reminder(project_id)
  @project = Project.find project_id
  @user    = @project.user

  mail(to: user_email(@user), subject: "Project Reminder")
end
```

And the relevant code in my controller:

```
def remind
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id])
  UserMailer.project_reminder(@project.id).deliver_later(wait: 10.minutes)
end
```

Also, I'm using sidekiq 4.1.0 with redis as my queue adapter.

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610626/ruby-mailer-wrong-number-of-arguments

Comment: Not the same thing, that's an unrelated issue to the error I'm getting above.

Comment: Can you remove the silencers in your `backtrace_silencers.rb` initializer and show more lines of the stack trace?